# Spring Kafka committing offset after BackoffException

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I have to use Spring kafka(without spring!Crazy? but its true :) ) and I have the following scenario:
Consumer with auto commit configured and is a record listener(not batch);
The listener can throw 2 types of exception: BackoffException and GeneralSystemException.
On BackoffException, the error handler should seek partitions,pause the partition and NOT commit the record;
On GeneralSystemException it should send to another delay topic and COMMIT the offset.

The problem is even for BackoffException, my offset is being commited because isAckAfterHandling is true. If I set it to false, I ll have problem with the another exception.

One workaroud I found it is: create a custom common error handler, keep isAckAfterHandling = true, do the seeks and pause, and return a Exception in case of BackoffException;

But I am wonder how spring automatically leads with that scenario if, for example, you have a consumer using KafkaBackoffAwareMessageListenerAdapter and DefaultErrorHandler as the error handler and auto commit = true. looking into the code, looks like the handler will seeks correctly but will commit the offset that cause the BackoffException. In case on rebalance that message would be lost.

Like I said, If I use a custom error handler and, in case of BackoffException, throw a error to the container(after doing seeks and pause) that solves my problem but looks like a workaround.

I believe if spring had a isAckAfterHandle(Exception ex), should solve this kind of problem tho.

It turns out that is by design we should always return exceptions for a non recovered record, so my solution ended up not being a workaround like I said.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can possibly use the framework without Spring - you will lose all kinds of features (e.g. event publishing).

When `enable.auto.commit` is true; the container has nothing to do with committing offsets, it is handled internally by the `kafka-clients`.

Comment: No; all commits by the container are disabled if we detect that the consumer factory has the `enable.auto.commit` property explicitly set to true. See `ListenerConsumer.autoCommit`.

Comment: One more time; when `enable.auto.commit` is true, the container has no bearing on the commit logic; it is all done by the `KafkaConsumer` internally, based on the `auto.commit.interval.ms`. When disabled, the container commits the offset in a much more deterministic fashion.

Comment: I think you have some misunderstandings about how Kafka works. It maintains 2 pointers the committed offset and the current position. They have no relation to each other, except that the current position is set to the committed offset when a consumer first consumes. Not committing an offset in an active consumer will have no impact on the current position. The `DefaultErrorHandler` performs seek operations in order to reprocess the unprocessed records on the next commit. The `KafkaBackoffAwareMessageListenerAdapter` is not intended for user use; it is part of the non-blocking retry logic.

Comment: Using auto commit is simply not compatible with the default error handler, because the client might commit the offset after the error handler has performed the seeks. Just turn it off and let the container completely manage the offsets.

Comment: `>I am doing this throw...` the error handler should always throw an exception, unless the record is recovered by sending it to the recoverer after retries are exhausted. That is how it is designed.